# Using dask.distributed with rioxarray rio.to_raster results in `ValueError: Lock is not yet acquired`

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, locking, geospatial, dask-distributed

I am trying to write some code using `dask.distributed.Client` and `rioxarray to_raster` that:

1. Concatenates two rasters (dask arrays)
2. Applies a function across all blocks in the concatenated array
3. Writes the final array to a ".tif" file

However the code fails either with a `ValueError: Lock is not yet acquired` or `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'map_blocks.<locals>._wrapper'` error depending on what type of `lock` I use.

I'm using a local cluster and want to run the code across multiple threads and 1 worker. I've written the following minimum reproducible example:

```py
def test():
    from osgeo import gdal
    import rasterio
    from rasterio.transform import Affine
    import xarray as xr
    import rioxarray
    from dask.distributed import Client, Lock
    import numpy as np

    # Create georeferenced example rasters
    x = np.linspace(-90, 90, 100)
    y = np.linspace(90, -90, 100)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z1 =  np.abs(((X - 10) ** 2 + (Y - 10) ** 2) / 1 ** 2)
    Z2 =  np.abs(((X + 10) ** 2 + (Y + 10) ** 2) / 2.5 ** 2)
    Z =  (Z1 - Z2)

    xres = (x[-1] - x[0]) / len(x)
    yres = (y[-1] - y[0]) / len(y)

    transform = Affine.translation(x[0] - xres / 2, y[0] - yres / 2) * Affine.scale(xres, yres)

    with rasterio.open(
            "example.tif",
            mode="w",
            driver="GTiff",
            height=Z.shape[0],
            width=Z.shape[1],
            count=1,
            dtype=Z.dtype,
            crs="+proj=latlong",
            transform=transform,
    ) as new_dataset:
            new_dataset.write(Z, 1)


    with rasterio.open(
            "example2.tif",
            mode="w",
            driver="GTiff",
            height=Z.shape[0],
            width=Z.shape[1],
            count=1,
            dtype=Z.dtype,
            crs="+proj=latlong",
            transform=transform,
    ) as new_dataset:
            new_dataset.write(Z, 1)

    # Use dask distributed and rioxarray to open the rasters
    chunkDimsX = 10
    chunkDimsY = 10
    with Client(threads_per_worker=6, n_workers=1, processes=False) as client:

        with rioxarray.open_rasterio("example.tif", chunks=(chunkDimsX, chunkDimsY), lock=False) as xds:
            
            with rioxarray.open_rasterio("example2.tif", chunks=(chunkDimsX, chunkDimsY), lock=False) as xds2:
                
                concatRaster = xr.concat([xds, xds2], dim='band').chunk({'band': 1, 'x': chunkDimsX, 'y': chunkDimsY})
                concatRaster = concatRaster.map_blocks(lambda x: x + 1, template=concatRaster)
                concatRaster.rio.write_nodata(0, inplace=True)

                concatRaster.rio.to_raster('concat.tif', tiled=True, lock = Lock(client=client), overwrite=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

When I run the above, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 52, in test
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_array.py", line 1125, in to_raster
    return RasterioWriter(raster_path=raster_path).to_raster(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_writer.py", line 295, in to_raster
    return dask.array.store(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 1236, in store
    compute_as_if_collection(Array, store_dsk, map_keys, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 402, in compute_as_if_collection
    return schedule(dsk2, keys, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 3275, in get
    results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 2372, in gather
    return self.sync(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\lock.py", line 163, in release
    raise ValueError("Lock is not yet acquired")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Lock is not yet acquired
```

I tried changing the `Lock` argument to be `True` instead of the dask.distributed client:

```
concatRaster.rio.to_raster('concat.tif', tiled=True, lock = True, overwrite=True)
```

But I get the following error:

```
2024-03-22 10:21:45,634 - distributed.protocol.pickle - ERROR - Failed to serialize <ToPickle: HighLevelGraph with 1 layers.
<dask.highlevelgraph.HighLevelGraph object at 0x1a0162f93d0>
 0. 1787078771392
>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\pickle.py", line 63, in dumps
    result = pickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'map_blocks.<locals>._wrapper'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\pickle.py", line 68, in dumps
    pickler.dump(x)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'map_blocks.<locals>._wrapper'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\pickle.py", line 81, in dumps
    result = cloudpickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 1479, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 1245, in dump
    return super().dump(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\pickle.py", line 63, in dumps
    result = pickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'map_blocks.<locals>._wrapper'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\pickle.py", line 68, in dumps
    pickler.dump(x)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'map_blocks.<locals>._wrapper'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 353, in serialize
    header, frames = dumps(x, context=context) if wants_context else dumps(x)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 76, in pickle_dumps
    frames[0] = pickle.dumps(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\pickle.py", line 81, in dumps
    result = cloudpickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 1479, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 1245, in dump
    return super().dump(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 52, in test
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_array.py", line 1125, in to_raster
    return RasterioWriter(raster_path=raster_path).to_raster(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_writer.py", line 295, in to_raster
    return dask.array.store(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 1236, in store
    compute_as_if_collection(Array, store_dsk, map_keys, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 402, in compute_as_if_collection
    return schedule(dsk2, keys, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 3255, in get
    futures = self._graph_to_futures(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 3151, in _graph_to_futures
    header, frames = serialize(ToPickle(dsk), on_error="raise")
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birch\miniconda3\envs\foresceStsimConnector\foresce-stsim-connector-py-conda\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 379, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str_x) from exc
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type HighLevelGraph', '<ToPickle: HighLevelGraph with 1 layers.\n<dask.highlevelgraph.HighLevelGraph object at 0x1a0162f93d0>\n 0. 1787078771392\n>')
```

It looks like it's related to the dask array `map_blocks` method.

I'm fairly inexperienced using dask, so any help with deciphering why these error messages are occurring and what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!